# Colorizing a diff of diffs in git

Tags: bash, git, colors, diff, colordiff

**The setup**

I wrote a script that checks if a merge commit was resolved successfully by displaying a diff of diffs before an after the merge. For example, if my history looks like this:

```
* 5c8cb0d2 merge result
|\
| * 3685c2ea branch2 commit b
| * 556dcd25 branch2 commit a
* | bb72182a branch1 commit
|/
* 45d827a3 common ancestor
```

I first do a diff from `45d827a3 common ancestor` to `bb72182a branch1 commit` (original changes on branch1) and then a diff from `3685c2ea branch2 commit b` to `5c8cb0d2 merge result` (showing how branch2 was "enriched" by branch1).

Ideally, these 2 diffs would be that same, but if there is a conflict (say branch 2 renamed a function that branch 1 used), I would need to solve it in the merge commit. In order to verify that the merge commit correctly solved these problem and didn't accidentally mess something up, *i do a diff on those 2 diffs*.

**The problem**

The coloring on the resulting diff is not great. For example, if I accidentally remove lines that were added in branch 2, they will be displayed in green, because the original diff didn't contain those lines, but the new diff does. In short I need to apply the following table, based on the start of the line:

- `++` = green (line was added by new diff but not changed in old diff)
- `+-` = red (line was removed in new diff but not changed in old diff)
- `-+` = red (line is not changed in new diff but was added in old diff)
- `--` = green (line is not changed in new diff but was removed in old diff)
- `+` = white (new context line only)
- `-` = white (old context line only)

**Partial solution**

I was able to implement one rule by using `sed`, but I don't know how I would apply all of them at once. For example, implementing the `-+` rule:

```
git diff ... | { esc=$(printf '\033'); sed -E "s/(^\-\+.*)/${esc}[0;31m\1${esc}[0m/"; }
```

Comment: FYI, the [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org/) program is actually a perl script which does different things depending on what kind of `diff` input it is processing (plain diff, context diff, unified diff, wdiff, etc).  It wouldn't be difficult to add a new type to the script (maybe `diffdiff`) to do the colorising you want.  Or maybe submit it as a feature-request on [github](https://github.com/daveewart/colordiff). Or submit a patch/pull-request if you manage to do it yourself.

Comment: BTW, `git` itself does not use `colordiff`, it does its own colourising.  But you can pipe `git`'s output into `colordiff`.

Comment: Have you tried `git range-diff`?  It provides a diff over two ranges.

Comment: @bk2204 TBH `git range-diff` is kind of useless, at least without additional parameters. Used on a merge commit that accidentally removed dozens of lines that it shouldn't have just prints 2 lines `1:  cfc83158 = 1:  cfc83158 description1
2:  0d38ffde = 2:  0d38ffde decriotion2`, it tells me nothing about if or what went wrong. The original "diff of diffs" solution correctly identifies the problems.